# Getting sql syntax error for update query

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, syntax-error

I'm trying to update some customer details but i get the error: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
PaperWorkRequired = 1, BookingInRequired = 0, TailLiftRequired = 1, OpeningTimes at line 1

Paperwork, booking and tail lift are check boxes and opening times is a text box. These options don't need to be filled in (which is way BookingInRequired is equal to zero since the check box is empty).

```
public static void UpdateCustomer(int CustomerID, string Name, int AccountType, string AccountCode, string Add1, string Add2, string Add3, string Town, int TownID, int CountryID, int CurrencyType, int CountyID, string PostCode, string ContactName, string Phone, string Email, int IsActive, int ModifiedByUser, string Website, string VATNo, int PORequired, int CreditTerms, int CreditDays, int VATCodeID, int COD, string VATAuthNo, int PrintBankDetails, int VATExempt, DateTime VATExpiry, 
    string SignedCreditApplcation, DateTime FinancialYearEnd, string FinancialSummary, DateTime CreditReviewDate, string CreditReviewComments, string DefaultInvoiceType, string DownloadToAccountCode, int PODRequired, decimal FuelSurcharge,
    string InvoiceInstructions, string DeliveryInstructions, int DeliveryInstructionsField, string CollectionInstuctions, int CollectionInstructionsField, string SpecialInstructions, int SpecialInstructionsField, int FOC, string DefaultPONumber, int OnHold, int PrintVAT, int PickByOrder, int IncludeInSelectStock, string GroupAccountCode, DateTime AccreditationExpiry, string AccreditedBy, DateTime AccreditedDate, int SendToWeb, int Rank, string SalesRep, int ShowProductionNote,
    string WebsiteCheckDate, string WebsiteComments, int Facebook, int PaperRecordOnFile, int FSCReq, string QuoteType, int PalletNetwork, string CustomerRequirement, int CustomerRequirementField, int ServiceLevel, int DefaultCreditorID, int ManualLotNo, DateTime DiscountReviewDate, decimal CreditLimitAmount, DateTime? AccountDisabledDate, string AccountDisabledMsg,
    int PaperWorkRequired, int BookInRequired, int TailLiftRequired, string OpeningTimes, string EquipmentRequired, string WeighInOut)
{
    string sql = "proc_UpdateCustomer";

    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE customer SET Name = '" + Name.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "AccountType = " + AccountType + ", " +
                                                  "AccountCode = '" + AccountCode.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Add1 = '" + Add1.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Add2 = '" + Add2.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Add3 = '" + Add3.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Town = '" + Town.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "TownID = " + TownID + ", " +
                                                  "CountryID = " + CountryID + ", " +
                                                  "CountyID = " + CountyID + ", " +
                                                  "CurrencyType = " + CurrencyType + ", " +
                                                  "PostCode = '" + PostCode.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "ContactName = '" + ContactName.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Phone = '" + Phone.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Email = '" + Email.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "IsActive = " + IsActive + ", " +
                                                  "ModifiedByUser = " + ModifiedByUser + ", " +
                                                  "ModifiedDate = NOW()," +
                                                  "Website = '" + Website.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "VATNo = '" + VATNo.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "CreditTermsID = " + CreditTerms + "," +
                                                  "CreditDays = " + CreditDays + "," +
                                                  "VATCodeID = " + VATCodeID + "," +
                                                  "COD = " + COD + ", " +
                                                  "VATAuthNo = '" + VATAuthNo.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "PrintBankDetails = " + PrintBankDetails + ", " +
                                                  "VATExempt = " + VATExempt + ",  " +
                                                  "VATExpiry = '" + VATExpiry.Year + "-" + VATExpiry.Month + "-" + VATExpiry.Day + "', " +
                                                  "FinancialYearEnd = '" + FinancialYearEnd.Year + "-" + FinancialYearEnd.Month + "-" + FinancialYearEnd.Day + "', " +
                                                  "FinancialSummary ='" + FinancialSummary.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "SignedCreditApplication = '" + SignedCreditApplcation.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "CreditReviewedDate = '" + CreditReviewDate.Year + "-" + CreditReviewDate.Month + "-" + CreditReviewDate.Day + "', " +
                                                  "CreditReviewComments = '" + CreditReviewComments.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "DefaultInvoiceType = '" + DefaultInvoiceType.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "DownloadToAccountCode ='" + DownloadToAccountCode.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "PODRequired = " + PODRequired + ", " +
                                                  "FuelSurcharge= " + FuelSurcharge + ", " +
                                                  "InvoiceInstructions = '" + InvoiceInstructions.Replace("'", "''") + "'," +
                                                  "DeliveryInstructions = '" + DeliveryInstructions.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "DeliveryInstructionsField = " + DeliveryInstructionsField + ", " +
                                                  "CollectionInstructions ='" + CollectionInstuctions.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "CollectionInstructionsField = " + CollectionInstructionsField + ", " +
                                                  "SpecialInstructions ='" + SpecialInstructions.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "SpecialInstructionsField = " + SpecialInstructionsField + ", " +
                                                  "FOC = " + FOC + ",  " +
                                                  "DefaultPO = '" + DefaultPONumber.Replace("'", "''") + "'," +
                                                  "PORequired = " + PORequired + ", " +
                                                  "OnHold = " + OnHold + ", " +
                                                  "PrintVAT = " + PrintVAT + ", " +
                                                  "IncludeInSelectStock = " + IncludeInSelectStock + ", " +
                                                  "PickByOrder = " + PickByOrder + ", " +
                                                  "AccreditationExpiry = '" + AccreditationExpiry.Year + "-" + AccreditationExpiry.Month + "-" + AccreditationExpiry.Day + "'," +
                                                  "AccreditedDate = '" + AccreditedDate.Year + "-" + AccreditedDate.Month + "-" + AccreditedDate.Day + "'," +
                                                  "AccreditedBy = '" + AccreditedBy.Replace("'", "''") + "'," +
                                                  "GroupAccountCode = '" + GroupAccountCode.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "SendToWeb = " + SendToWeb + ", " +
                                                  "SalesRep = '" + SalesRep.Replace("'", "''") + "'," +
                                                  "ShowProductionNote = " + ShowProductionNote + ", " +
                                                  "WebsiteCheckDate = '" + WebsiteCheckDate.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "WebsiteComments = '" + WebsiteComments.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Facebook = " + Facebook + ", " +
                                                  "PaperRecordOnFile = " + PaperRecordOnFile + ", " +
                                                  "FSCReq = " + FSCReq + ", " +
                                                  "QuoteType = '" + QuoteType.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "Rank = " + Rank + ", " +
                                                  "PalletNetwork = " + PalletNetwork + ", " +
                                                  "CustomerRequirement ='" + CustomerRequirement.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "CustomerRequirementField = " + CustomerRequirementField + ", " +
                                                  "ServiceLevel = " + ServiceLevel + ", " +
                                                  "ManualLotNo = " + ManualLotNo + ", " +
                                                  "DiscountReviewDate = '" + DiscountReviewDate.Year + "-" + DiscountReviewDate.Month + "-" + DiscountReviewDate.Day + "', " +
                                                  "CreditLimitAmount = " + CreditLimitAmount + ", " +
                                                  "DefaultCreditorID = " + DefaultCreditorID + ", " +
                                                  "AccountDisabledDate = ?AccountDisabledDate," +
                                                  "AccountDisabledMsg = ?AccountDisabledMsg " +
                                                  "PaperWorkRequired = " + PaperWorkRequired + ", " +
                                                  "BookingInRequired = " + BookInRequired + ", " +
                                                  "TailLiftRequired = " + TailLiftRequired + ", " +
                                                  "OpeningTimes ='" + OpeningTimes.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "EquipmentRequired ='" + EquipmentRequired.Replace("'", "''") + "', " +
                                                  "WeighInOut ='" + WeighInOut.Replace("'", "''") +
                                                  "WHERE ID = " + CustomerID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("AccountDisabledDate", AccountDisabledDate));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("AccountDisabledMsg", AccountDisabledMsg));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `AccountDisabledMsg = ?AccountDisabledMsg " +
  "PaperWorkRequired = " + PaperWorkRequired +` you are missing , after AccountDisabledMsg try `AccountDisabledMsg = ?AccountDisabledMsg ," +
  "PaperWorkRequired = " + PaperWorkRequired +`

Comment: use paramters and save yourself a lot of grief

Comment: Also use parameters like other users are saying it will help you to avoid sql injection pblm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your query building you are missing a comma
after `?AccountDsibaledMsg` as below

```
AccountDisabledMsg = ?AccountDisabledMsg " + 
"PaperWorkRequired = " + PaperWorkRequired +
```

put a comma and try

```
 AccountDisabledMsg = ?AccountDisabledMsg ," + 
"PaperWorkRequired = " + PaperWorkRequired +
```

But always try parameterized query because it will make you debugging easy as well as avoid sql injection problem

Comment: thanks it worked but now it's saying there's an error near
 WHERE ID = 44650 at line 1. It doesn't matter which customer I try to update. Is there something else in the code I'm missing?

Comment: @user2026041 `"WeighInOut ='" + WeighInOut.Replace("'", "''") +
                                                  "WHERE ID = " + CustomerID;` here you started `'` after `=` which is not ended before `Where`

Comment: ok I changed the code to this:  "WeighInOut ='" + WeighInOut.Replace("'", "''") + "'" + " WHERE ID = " + CustomerID;

Comment: Still error? if so assign this string to a variable and messagebox the same and check whether the query is correct